# USB Get Descriptor request of length zero

Tags: c, usb

I have a wired USB mouse that is fully functional except for this issue. The issue is that when I send a standard Get Descriptor request to read the product string, the communication line between the mouse and the PC freeze but the mouse is still functional(meaning I can't send anymore commands until I unplug and plug the mouse).

This only happens if the request to read the product string is of length zero otherwise I don't see the issue. Have you seen this issue before? What is causing it?

I'm using windows 10

Comment: The mouse might incorrectly implement the USB protocol (or your request might be invalid) and send an incomplete response (or none at all). If so, the PC (are you using Windows?) will wait for the missing response and not accept any further request on this particular endpoint.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. The request is not invalid, since I have another mouse that is fine with a zero length Get Descriptor. (The mouse uses different code and IC)

Comment: What does the USB documentation say? Other device may also by erratic and handle illegal request by error.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting a string descriptor and setting the length of your request to 0 is an unusual thing and was perhaps not tested by the developers of your mouse's firmware, so it is not surprising that the firmware would have some bugs that cause it to crash.  You should probably just avoid making such requests.  I'm not sure what you are using that request for but you could probably figure out another way to accomplish it.